# ReduxForm - enableReinitialize doesn't update values in nested FieldArrays

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-form

In my form I am passing the initialvalues through the below code.

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
     return {
       initialValues: {
       POItems: state.poItems.poItems
     }
  }
}

AddCustomerPOItems = reduxForm({
  form: 'AddCustomerPOItemsForm',
  enableReinitialize: true,
})(AddCustomerPOItems)

AddCustomerPOItems = connect(mapStateToProps, poItems)(AddCustomerPOItems)

export default AddCustomerPOItems
```

This issue is in nested field array.
When a new item is added reducers will update the state and initialize the fields and works correctly, but if I modify a field, the reducers works fine and updates the state correctly but the values are not getting initialized.

In table 1 its a fieldarray and table 2 (Yellow one) is a nested fieldarray of first table

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `componentDidMount` and `componentDidUpdate` lifecycle hooks to call `this.props.initialize(…)` to reinitialize the form whenever the data changes.

https://redux-form.com/7.2.3/docs/api/props.md/#-code-initialize-data-object-function-code-

You may also have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43631435/redux-form-defaultvalue/43631727#43631727), since it deals with a quite similar Problem.